Does "You Have Arrived at Your Destination" support Vitek's idea of human lives having three acts?
"You Have Arrived at Your Destination" is a short story by Amor Towles in the Forward collection. It is set in a near-ish future with a fertility clinic, Vitek, which claims to allow parents to choose their child's life trajectory. That life trajectory is presented as a short film with clear "acts". For example, a first "act" where life comes easy to the kid in childhood, a second "act" where they run into issues as an adult, and a third "act" where they reinvent their life with the wisdom they gained during their second act. This is a "third-act comeback".
[The remainder of this question will contain spoilers for the story.]
The Vitek employee who explains this to Sam (the main character) defends the clinic's three-act structure. According to him, the three-act structure in literature originates from humans recognizing fundamental patterns in their lives. He goes on to use the life histories of Sam and Sam's wife to put them into "acts": Sam in his third, Sam's wife in her second.
I have doubts about the applicability of the three-act structure in literature, but that's not the point of this question, so you may assume that the "three-act structure" is a well-defined and recurrent literary form. However, does the short story support the idea that human lives fit into three-act structures?
After the Vitek employee shows the short films, Sam goes to a bar. A guy there gives Sam a talking-to about the fragility of life's plans. The story ends with Sam taking his DNA sample back from Vitek and presumably cancelling their fertility treatment contract. This last act is clearly a rejection, but a somewhat ambiguous one. (Is he rejecting the idea of controlling his child's future, the idea of predicting his child's future, the way that Vitek packages life trajectories, etc.?)
Does Sam's final choice indicate a story message against Vitek's three-act structure? Or is it a rejection of something unrelated? If it's unrelated, does the story as a whole take a position on the correctness of Vitek's three-act structure for human lives? On the one hand, the Vitek employee is allowed quite a long and detailed defense of the structure, but on the other, I have an inkling that the post-clinic story events are meant as proof that the three-act structure doesn't work for human lives, but I can't explain my arguments well to myself.
